# Why TCP is faster than UDP in my Java code?

Tags: java, sockets, tcp, udp

I wrote a code to measure the speed of TCP and UDP.
However, I have found that UDP is faster than TCP in some cases.

[image]

I'm curious about four things.

1. Why is TCP faster than UDP when the packet size is 400B? (in AWS Ohio region)
2. Why is TCP faster than UDP when the packet size is 4KB? (in all environments)
3. Why is TCP faster than UDP when the packet size is 40KB? (in the local environment)
4. Why are the speeds similar regardless of packet size? (UDP in the AWS Ohio environment)

Below is the code I wrote.

- The 'currentTimeMillis' value is repeatedly stored in 8Byte units in the packet message. Bit value corruption was detected by checking if the same value is repeated in units of 8 bytes when packets are received.
- The server side sent the same data to the client as soon as it was received. (SendBack)
- The client side created a thread in units of 10 ms and transmitted the packet to the server. (Sender)

```
import java.net.*;

public class UDPSender { //Send and receive

    private final DatagramSocket socket;

    private final String RECEVER_IP;
    private final int PORT;
    private final int SIZE;
    private final int REPEAT;

    private int COUNT = 0;
    private int WRONG_COUNT = 0;
    private int TIME_SUM = 0;

    private synchronized void COUNT() { COUNT++; }
    private synchronized void WRONG_COUNT() { WRONG_COUNT++; }
    private synchronized void TIME_SUM(int time) { TIME_SUM += time; }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        if (args.length == 0) args = new String[]{"192.168.1.33", "53135", "40000", "100"};

        new UDPSender(args[0], Integer.parseInt(args[1]), Integer.parseInt(args[2]), Integer.parseInt(args[3]));
    }

    public UDPSender(String ip, int port, int size, int repeat) throws Exception {
        this.RECEVER_IP = ip;
        this.PORT = port;
        this.SIZE = size;
        this.REPEAT = repeat;

        this.socket = new DatagramSocket();

        for (int i = 1; i <= REPEAT; i++) {
            send(i);

            Thread.sleep(10);
        }
    }

    private void send(int id) throws Exception {
        new Thread(() -> {
            try {
                byte[] buffer = createData();
                InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByName(RECEVER_IP);
                DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(buffer, buffer.length, address, PORT);

                socket.send(packet);
                System.out.println(id + " messages sent");
        
                receive(socket);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }).start();
    }

    private void receive(DatagramSocket socket) throws Exception {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[SIZE];
        DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(buffer, buffer.length);

        socket.receive(packet);

        long sendTime = validateData(packet.getData());
        long taken = System.currentTimeMillis() - sendTime;
        COUNT();

        if (sendTime == -1) {
            WRONG_COUNT();

            return;
        }

        TIME_SUM((int)taken);

        System.out.println(COUNT + " messages received (including " + WRONG_COUNT + " wrong message) / Time taken " + taken + "ms (Average " + String.format("%.3f", (double)TIME_SUM / COUNT) + "ms)");
    }

    private byte[] createData() {
        long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        byte[] buffer = new byte[SIZE];

        for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i += 8) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
                buffer[i + j] = (byte) (currentTime >> (56 - (8 * j)));
            }
        }

        return buffer;
    }

    private long validateData(byte[] data) {
        long sendTime = -1;

        for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i += 8) {
            long time = 0;
            for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
                time |= ((long) data[i + j] & 0xff) << (56 - (8 * j));
            }

            if (sendTime != -1 && time != sendTime) {
                return -1;
            }

            sendTime = time;
        }

        return sendTime;
    }

}
```

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class TCPSender { //Send and receive

    private final String RECEVER_IP;
    private final int PORT;
    private final int SIZE;
    private final int REPEAT;

    private int COUNT = 0;
    private int WRONG_COUNT = 0;
    private int TIME_SUM = 0;

    private synchronized void COUNT() { COUNT++; }
    private synchronized void WRONG_COUNT() { WRONG_COUNT++; }
    private synchronized void TIME_SUM(int time) { TIME_SUM += time; }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        if (args.length == 0) args = new String[]{"192.168.1.33", "53135", "40000", "100"};
    
        new TCPSender(args[0], Integer.parseInt(args[1]), Integer.parseInt(args[2]), Integer.parseInt(args[3]));
    }

    public TCPSender(String ip, int port, int size, int repeat) throws Exception {
        this.RECEVER_IP = ip;
        this.PORT = port;
        this.SIZE = size;
        this.REPEAT = repeat;

        for (int i = 1; i <= REPEAT; i++) {
            send(i);

            Thread.sleep(10);
        }
    }

    private void send(int id) throws Exception {
        new Thread(() -> {
            try {
                Socket socket = new Socket(RECEVER_IP, PORT);

                byte[] buffer = createData();
                OutputStream os = socket.getOutputStream();
                os.write(buffer);
                os.flush();

                System.out.println(id + " messages sent");

                receive(socket);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }).start();
    }

    private void receive(Socket socket) throws Exception {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[SIZE];

        InputStream is = socket.getInputStream();
        int left = SIZE;
        while (left > 0) {
            int read = is.read(buffer, SIZE - left, left);

            left -= read;
        }

        long sendTime = validateData(buffer);
        long taken = System.currentTimeMillis() - sendTime;
        COUNT();

        if (sendTime == -1) {
            WRONG_COUNT();

            return;
        }

        TIME_SUM((int)taken);

        System.out.println(COUNT + " messages received (including " + WRONG_COUNT + " wrong message) / Time taken " + taken + "ms (Average " + String.format("%.3f", (double)TIME_SUM / COUNT) + "ms)");
    }

    private byte[] createData() {
        long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        byte[] buffer = new byte[SIZE];

        for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i += 8) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
                buffer[i + j] = (byte) (currentTime >> (56 - (8 * j)));
            }
        }

        return buffer;
    }

    private long validateData(byte[] data) {
        long sendTime = -1;

        for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i += 8) {
            long time = 0;
            for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
                time |= ((long) data[i + j] & 0xff) << (56 - (8 * j));
            }

            if (sendTime != -1 && time != sendTime) {
                return -1;
            }

            sendTime = time;
        }

        return sendTime;
    }

}
```

```
import java.net.*;

class UDPSendBack { //Receive and send

    private final DatagramSocket socket;
    private final int SIZE;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        if (args.length == 0) args = new String[]{"53135", "40000"};

        new UDPSendBack(Integer.parseInt(args[0]), Integer.parseInt(args[1]));
    }

    public UDPSendBack(int port, int size) throws Exception {
        this.SIZE = size;
        this.socket = new DatagramSocket(port);

        while (true) {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[SIZE];
            DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(buffer, buffer.length);
            socket.receive(packet);
    
            new Thread(() -> {
                DatagramPacket sendPacket = new DatagramPacket(buffer, buffer.length, packet.getAddress(), packet.getPort());

                try {
                    socket.send(sendPacket);
        
                    System.out.println("Received message and send back");
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }).start();
        }
    }

}
```

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

class TCPSendBack { //Receive and send

    private final ServerSocket serverSocket;
    private final int SIZE;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        if (args.length == 0) args = new String[]{"53135", "40000"};

        new TCPSendBack(Integer.parseInt(args[0]), Integer.parseInt(args[1]));
    }

    public TCPSendBack(int port, int size) throws Exception {
        this.SIZE = size;
        this.serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);

        while (true) {
            Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
    
            new Thread(() -> {
                byte[] data = new byte[SIZE];
                try {
                    InputStream is = socket.getInputStream();

                    int left = SIZE;
                    while (left > 0) {
                        int read = is.read(data, SIZE - left, left);

                        left -= read;
                    }

                    OutputStream os = socket.getOutputStream();
                    os.write(data);
                    os.flush();

                    System.out.println("Received message and send back");
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    return;
                }
            }).start();
        }
    }

}
```